# Adding a license key to a zip file

Tags: code-access-security

I've got a product that ships as a zip file. I'd like to add some security to it or perhaps a password or license key to deter unauthorized trading of the file. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [password protect the zip](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/8730).

Comment: Wordpress requires the file to be in a zip format in order to install it using their default upload wizard. In my experience, I can't get Wordpress to work with a zipped file that has a password.

Comment: The workaround would be that the user would have to (1) unzip the file using the password and (2) rezip the file without using a password. That sounds simple but half the users are likely to mess it up, LOL.